# Get indices of strings in an array

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array in numpy which looks like this:

```
myarray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I would like to return an array of indices for `'b', 'c', 'd'` which looks like this:

```
myind = [1,2,3]
```

I need this indices array later to use it in a loop. I am using Python 2.7. Thanks folks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
In [61]: myarray = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

In [62]: search = np.array(['b', 'c', 'd'])

In [63]: np.searchsorted(myarray, search)
Out[63]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

If `myarray` is not alphabetically sorted, we need to use the additional argument `sorter` with it, like so -

```
In [64]: myarray = np.array(['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f'])

In [65]: search = np.array(['b', 'c', 'd'])

In [67]: sidx = np.argsort(myarray)

In [69]: sidx[np.searchsorted(myarray, search, sorter=sidx)]
Out[69]: array([2, 4, 1])
```

Comment: myarray is not sorted, but the strings location should not change.

Comment: @Bob Consider accepting one of the solutions that worked best for you. Read more about accepting solutions here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If your array does not contain any duplicates then np.searchsorted should do the trick. if your array contains duplicates then you have to use np.argwhere
Examples:

```
input_array = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','a'])
search = np.array(['a','b','c'])

np.searchsorted(input_array, search)
output >> array([0, 1, 2])

np.argwhere(input_array == 'a')
output >> array([[0],[6]])
```

For a more general solution you can do

```
np.concatenate( (np.argwhere(input_array == 'a') ,
                 np.argwhere(input_array == 'b'), 
                 np.argwhere(input_array == 'c') )  )
output >> array([[0],[6],[1],[2]])
```

Comment: For this particular case I don't have duplicates. But in other instances I do have duplicates. I appreciate your solutions. Thanks.